# scrolltop with if less than not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop

hello i work to create simple parallax effect but there simple problem that the scroll top with if less not work, i need if the user to scroll to bottom please animate position of flowers to top:-20% left:-20% and if he scroll to top please animate position of flowers to top:0; left:0;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var flowersLeft = $(".flowers-topleft")
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
            $(flowersLeft).animate({
                top: "-18%",
                left: "-20%"
            }, 600);
            $("body").css("background", "green");
        }
        else {
            $(flowersLeft).animate({
                top: "0",
                left: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("body").css("background", "black");
        }
    })
})
```

```css
html{
                height:100%;
            }
            body{
                height:6000px !important;
                background-color:#ff0000;
            }
            .flowers-topleft {
                width: 50%;
                height: 50%;
                position:fixed;
                top:auto;
                left:auto;
                background-image: url("http://cafefrida.ca/img/flowers-topleft.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: right bottom;
                background-size: cover !important;
            }
            .flowers-topright {
                width: 50%;
                height: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                background-image: url(http://cafefrida.ca/img/flowers-topright.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: left bottom;
                background-size: cover !important;
            }
            .flowers-bottomright {
                height: 58%;
                width: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                background-image: url(http://cafefrida.ca/img/flowers-bottomright.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: left top;
                background-size: cover !important;
            }
            .flowers-bottomleft {
                height: 50%;
                width: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-image: url(http://cafefrida.ca/img/flowers-bottomleft.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: right top;
                background-size: cover !important;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flowers-topleft"></div>
    <div class="flowers-topright"></div>
    <div class="flowers-bottomright"></div>
    <div class="flowers-bottomleft"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if I understood your problem correctly, but adding a simple `.stop()` before your `.animate()` will make your animations work correctly on scroll. But this is a very basic "parallax effect".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var flowersLeft = $(".flowers-topleft")
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
            $(flowersLeft).stop().animate({
                top: "-18%",
                left: "-20%"
            }, 600);
            $("body").css("background", "green");
        }
        else {
            $(flowersLeft).stop().animate({
                top: "0%",
                left: "0%"
            }, 600);
            $("body").css("background", "black");
        }
    })
})
```

`.stop()` will end every currently running animation on your element(s). See [.stop() jQuery api](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: not work as i need when i scroll to bottom the animation is moving very slowly.